# Optimize Radix Sort

Tags: c, sorting, binary, time-complexity, radix

For a programming assignment I had to create a radix sort algorithm that worked with floating point numbers in their binary versions. The end goal of the assignment was to sort 100 million floating point numbers in under 2 minutes.

The algorithm itself took me a while to get working but as of now it has been really efficient. I am able to sort the 100 million numbers in about 30 seconds. The important note is that the floats have to be converted to unsigned ints so that bit-wise operations can be applied to them. The code that I used to do that I saw in a video on Quake 3's Fast Inverse Square Root Algorithm. Here is the code that I wrote for the assignment.

```
void radixsort(float *array, unsigned int length, unsigned int bits) {
    double sum = 0;
    // Create buckets
    float *bucketsA = (float *) malloc(length * sizeof(float));
    float *bucketsB = (float *) malloc(length * sizeof(float));

    unsigned int aIndex = 0, bIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < bits; i++) {
        // Sort array using digit position d as the key.
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if (i == 0) sum += array[j];
            unsigned int conversion = * (unsigned int *) &array[j];
            int positionBit = nthBit(conversion, i);
            if (positionBit == 0) {
                bucketsA[aIndex] = array[j];
                aIndex++;
            }
            else {
                bucketsB[bIndex] = array[j];
                bIndex++;
            }
        }
        // Combine and move sorted buckets into original array
        if(i == bits - 1) {
            reverseArray(bucketsB, bIndex);
            memcpy(array,          bucketsB, (bIndex + 1) * sizeof(float));
            memcpy(array + bIndex, bucketsA, (aIndex + 1) * sizeof(float));
        }
        else {
            memcpy(array,           bucketsA, (aIndex + 1) * sizeof(float));
            memcpy(array + aIndex,  bucketsB, (bIndex + 1) * sizeof(float));
        }

        // Reset the memory of the buckets
        memset(&bucketsA[0], 0, sizeof(float) * length);
        memset(&bucketsB[0], 0, sizeof(float) * length);

        // Reset bucket index
        aIndex = bIndex = 0;
    }
    printf("Total: %f\n", sum);

    // Free reserved memory
    free(bucketsA);
    free(bucketsB);
}
```

I have two questions relating to the following code:

The first is that when I commented out freeing the reserved memory at the bottom I was expecting a segmentation fault but nothing happened, why is this? I might be a little confused on how memory on the heap and stack works but I thought that if the memory was not freed even though it is local it should cause an error. Freeing the memory actually slowed down the program as well.

The second question is does anyone see any obvious way to make the program run faster? I am already way below the minimum requirement for time and most of my classmates' programs are sorting the 100 million numbers in 1:30+ so I have nothing to worry about but I saw in a post someone managed to get their radix sort to run through 100 million in about 15 seconds. In this implementation I started with LSB so I wonder if starting with MSB will make the program faster but I don't have much time to really test with finals coming up. Thank you for the help.

EDIT: Here is the code for the nthBit and reverseArray

```
int nthBit(int number, int n) {
    return (number >> n) & 1;
}

void reverseArray(float *array, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (size / 2); i++) {
        float swap = array[size - 1 - i];
        array[size - 1 - i] = array[i];
        array[i] = swap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use `* (unsigned int *) &array[j]`. The behavior of that is not defined by the C standard. use `(union { float f; unsigned int u; }) {array[j]} .f`.

Comment: Not freeing memory means you hold onto memory you do not need anymore. That cannot cause an error except for making memory unavailable for other purposes. You get a segment fault when you **do** use memory you are **not** entitled to use and that memory is not mapped into memory with the permission (read/write/execute) you tried to use. You do not get a segment fault when you **do not** use memory you **are** entitled to use (still have allocated).

Comment: The definitions of `nthBit` and `reverseArray` are not shown. Reversing an array and then doing a `memcpy` is likely less efficient than directly copying the reverse into the destination.

Comment: Using two or more bits for the radix and four or more subarrays may be faster than using one bit at a time.

Comment: Instead of copying both `bucketsA` and `bucketsB` back to `array`, it may be faster to copy `bucketsB` to the end of `bucketsA` and then use `bucketsA` as the source array in the next iteration. This requires more code and likely pointers to rotate between the arrays in use.

Comment: `memset` of the arrays serves no purpose; they do not need to be erased.

Comment: @EricPostpischil For the reverseArray I did some research into copying the memory backwards and someone ran tests that showed it was about 3 times slower than just copying the memory normally. I don't know whether or not my implementation will be slower but that's a good point thank you.